# GeSHI new language

Tags: mediawiki, pygments, geshi

I running a mediawiki and want to use syntax highlighting. I am using the extension https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight for that.

That works pretty fine.
Alas I want to highlight a language that is not part of this extension. So I wrote an python egg to extend pygments so it can parse my language (using entry points). This works fine.

Now I am struggling to get both to work together. How do I tell the GeShi Extension of MediaWiki to use my pygments extension? What do I have to do, so that using `<syntaxhighlight lang="myLanguage">` will result in using my language lexer and style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. One has to edit the file SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi.lexers.php and add the lexer.
It's important to use only lowercase for the lexer name, otherwise the extension will not find the lexer.